# Solr query stops working correctly after I add EdgeNGramFilterFactory

Tags: solr, coldfusion

Everything works fine before I add `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`. It looks like the `OR` was affected. I'm not sure whether the `NOT` was affected.

I use Solr 3.4 built on ColdFusion 10.

Here is code in the schema.xml:

```xml
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>

    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            enablePositionIncrements="true"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Search just like below:

```
stcLocal.objSolrQuery.addFilterQuery(['Agency_tm:348D107C-EF12-AB1F-6D54EE4947F6257D OR AllParticipant_i:1']);
```

It works correctly once I remove the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`.

Comment: Whats the search text working earlier and not working now? If I get it, would good to help you on building the field type...

Comment: please mention the field type used for the field "AllParticipant_i"

Comment: <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="false"/>
    <dynamicField name="*_i"  type="sint"    indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
The value of AllParticipant_i is either 1 or 0.
The value of Agency_tm is the uuid created by coldfusion, length is 36, just looks like 348D107C-EF12-AB1F-6D54EE4947F6257D.
There should be 17 records returned but I got 16 records.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this field type for your field "Agency_tm"

```
<fieldType name="text_reference" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="front"/>
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="50" side="back"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: I tried as suggested, adn add a multiValued dynamicField(_tre), it really returned records I wanted. I found that the text_reference only have one back EdgeNGramFilterFactory in admin/schema.jsp though I set front first. But if I remove the back EdgeNGramFilterFactory from previous code it returned the records correctly too. But If I search by stcLocal.objSolrQuery.addFilterQuery(['AuthorisedAgency_tre:3671B5AD-0D4F-7B4F-3‌​69A024FB271E1F3']); it also don't return records I want.

Comment: did you analyse these on solr analysis tool?

Comment: I have tried with the above mentioned fieldtype for agency_tm with text "3671B5AD-0D4F-7B4F-3‌​‌​69A024FB271E1F3" and its shows it in the result... Whats your final fieldType for Agency_tm? How are you building the query?